# Views with Visibility Gone appear to be taking up space still

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a dialog Layout that has several views that are initialised as Visibility Gone. However the space for each of the Views still appears to be being allocated resulting in a very large gap between the top two permanent views and the bottom Button.

Below is the Layout file I'm using.

If anyone has any ideas that would be great.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/SearchTypeSpinner" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:prompt="@string/SearchPrompt"
    android:entries="@array/SearchTypes">
    </Spinner>
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/SearchText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SearchTypeSpinner"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone">
    </EditText>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/RadiusLabel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Search Radius"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SearchText"
    android:visibility="gone"
    style="@style/headerText">
    </TextView>
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/RadiusText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RadiusLabel"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone">
    </EditText>
  <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/StateSpinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RadiusText"
    android:entries="@array/states"
    android:prompt="@string/StatePrompt"
    android:visibility="gone">
    </Spinner>
     <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ShowResultsButton"
    android:text="Show Results"
    android:layout_alignBottom="true">
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the result that you are seeking? BTW it's android:layout_alignParentBottom if you want to use a boolean. Otherwise you need to provide a resource id.

Comment: What I want to do is depending on the option picked in the top spinner make certain views visible in such a way that there isn't a noticable gap between which ever is the visible views and the Button at the bottom